# Which thread is called when an android application is start.?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am new to android application development and want to know which thread is called when android application is start.? I searched about this question in Google but I can't get any satisfied answer. If anyone knows please help me.Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> When an application component starts and the application does not have
>   any other components running, the Android system starts a new Linux
>   process for the application with a single thread of execution. By
>   default, all components of the same application run in the same
>   process and thread (called the "main" thread). If an application
>   component starts and there already exists a process for that
>   application (because another component from the application exists),
>   then the component is started within that process and uses the same
>   thread of execution.

For further information [visit](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Comment: I think 2 or 3 thread will called when an app is start."main" is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

When a Android app is opened, by default, its main UI thread is started. It will be open until the app is destroyed. By default all your code is executed in this thread. All UI rendering, animations are done in this thread.

If you created any other background threads (to do any operations like network access, database access, image processing), in the `Application` class or the launcher `Activity` class, then those threads are started, when the app is opened.